# Get the image to appear larger with moving my other elements on my page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the exact thing i've got to do:

> Appropriate JavaScript and html so that when the user moves the mouse
>   over a thumbnail image of one particular type of room that is on
>   special offer, a full size (larger) image relating to it is displayed
>   (note that the display of a larger image should not cause other page
>   elements to move). When the user moves the mouse away from the
>   thumbnail image, the larger image should disappear.

[Here is my website](http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/accommodation.html).

I just want to be able to hover over those image and get them to appear above the page, without altering how the page looks now.

This is my javascript section at the moment;

```
div = {
    show: function(elem) {
        document.getElementById(elem).style.visibility = 'visible';
    },
    hide: function(elem) {
        document.getElementById(elem).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

But i'm unsure if that is right or now for what i want,

Then this is the html;

```
<a href="images/garden2.jpg" class="preview"><img src="images/garden2.jpg" width="201"       height="143" alt="Garden Room" onMouseOver="div.show('div1')" onMouseOut="div.hide('div1')"/></a>
        <div id="div1"><img src="images/garden2.jpg" alt="Garden Room" /></div>
```

but that creates a div below the image and alters the my elements which is not what i want to happen.

Comment: -1, please post some code.

Comment: Yeah i have added my code now, only just joined as you can probably tell sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want some element to appear over other elements this element need to be positioned - the best way in your case is to set all containers element - meaning elements that contains the original shown image and the hidden image - in style position relative - and the hidden image set absolute position and when you hover on the original image just show the hidden image as your coded already:

I made a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKPgv/) for you to understand

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/fellside22.jpg"><img src="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/fellside22.jpg" onMouseOver="div.show('div1')" onMouseOut="div.hide('div1')" /></a>
    <div id="div1" class="hid-img"><img src="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/fellside22.jpg" /></div>
<div>

<div class="container">
    <a href="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/garden2.jpg"><img src="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/garden2.jpg" onMouseOver="div.show('div2')" onMouseOut="div.hide('div2')" /></a>
    <div id="div2" class="hid-img"><img src="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/garden2.jpg" /></div>
<div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}

.container .hid-img{
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
}
```

js:

```
var div = {
    show: function(elem) {
        document.getElementById(elem).style.display = 'block';
    },
    hide: function(elem) {
        document.getElementById(elem).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
just add width,height to img tag http://jsfiddle.net/MKPgv/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simpler code like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/fellside22.jpg">
<img width="100" src="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/fellside22.jpg" />
<img class="fullsize" src="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/fellside22.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/garden2.jpg">
<img width="100" src="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/garden2.jpg" />
<img class="fullsize" src="http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/images/garden2.jpg" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

a .fullsize {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

a:hover .fullsize {
    display: inline;
}
```

JS:
-NONE-

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/84anu/
Preview http://jsfiddle.net/84anu/show/

Comment: Those answers are both good but I have to use JS to comply with the specification I've been given, the code I have used is probably on the wrong lines that I'm trying to achieve I'm a bit lost when it comes to JS.